# fazer pesquisa em duas planilhas com um form no vba

Tags: vba, algoritmo-de-busca, excel-vba

boa tarde pessoas!
meu problema e o seguinte: tenho um formulário com 2 textbox uma para nome de alunos e outra para sala e uma planilha com duas abas com os mesmo nomes (txtNomeAlunos, txtSalaAlunosplan1-nome, plan2-sala)
gostaria de saber como buscar essas informações nas 2 planilhas e trazer para minhas txts?
desde ja agradeço a todos

Answer (score 0):

Quer colocar o nome de todos os alunos em uma TextBox só? Como se fosse uma ComboBox?
Caso queira uma ComboBox com o nome de todos os alunos de uma planilha, faça o seguinte:
Vá na planilha e selecione as colunas, ou linhas (dependendo de como esteja) que está os nomes dos seus alunos e clique com o botão direito. Clique em "Definir nome". Defina um nome, por exemplo "ListaAlunos". 
Na sua Form, crie uma comboBox(Caixa de combinação), altere o nome para cmbListaAlunos (ou como queira, só para exemplo aqui). Clique duas vezes na combo e edicione esse código:

```
Dim cLoc As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("NOME DA SUA PLANILHA")

For Each cLoc In ws.Range("O NOME QUE VOCÊ DEFINIU PARA A SELEÇÃO")
    With Me.cmbListaAlunos 
        .AddItem cLoc.Value
    End With
Next cLoc
```

Este código irá adicionar todos os alunos da planilha nesta comboBox. Para acessar outra planilha é preciso ativa-la antes. Sheets(POSIÇÂO DA PLANILHA exemplo: 1, 2 ou 3).Activate.

Agora, se com seu sistema você quer mostrar os alunos correspondentes a uma sala especifica, poderá usar esse exemplo pra refletir. Pois o código será bem complexo de entender se for postado aqui.

Se essa resposta não era o que estava procurando, só desconsidere.